# why show diffrent between inline, inline-block in this case?

Tags: html, css

in this code, the div's height is one line height. if the second span's display is inline-block, the div's height is two line height.

```html
<div style="border:1px solid #00b0ff; width:200px;">
    <span style="width:100%;display: inline-block;background: #00b0ff">1</span>
    <span style="display: inline; background: #ff3d00;"></span>
</div>
<hr />
<div style="border:1px solid #00b0ff; width:200px;">
    <span style="width:100%;display: inline-block;background: #00b0ff">1</span>
    <span style="display: inline-block; background: #ff3d00;"></span>
</div>
```

how can I make that show only one line height?

Answer (score 0):

You can add font-size:0 to parent div and then add needed font-size for childs. It occurs because of space between inline-block elements.

```
<div style="border:1px solid #00b0ff; width:200px; font-size:0">
        <span style="width:100%;display: inline-block;background: #00b0ff; font-size:14px;">1</span>
        <span style="display: inline-block; background: #ff3d00;"></span>
</div>
```

Comment: why  the space  not aroused this between inline-block and inline element？

Comment: have another method to fix this? I want the font-size can inherit

Comment: probably, because only series of inline-blocks elements are divided like that

Comment: you can add negative margin to inline-block element in equal to 1em

Comment: oh, no. It doesn't work because of other span's width:100% .

Comment: May be you set use font size in rem for childs?

Comment: it will work too
<div style="border:1px solid #00b0ff; width:200px;">
    <span style="width:100%;display: inline-block;background: #00b0ff">1</span><!--
    --><span style="display: inline-block; background: #f00;"></span>
</div>

Comment: also you can add white-space:nowrap for parent div

Comment: white-space:nowrap  is a good idea. but setting it has a little diff with following a inline element. if the second span is not empty, the span will in second line , this is I want.

Comment: Why dont you want use solution with empty pseudo-class?
A space between inline-blocks is a space between them in html code. So, you can delete all spaces between your spans or use comment tag,  as I have already offered.

Answer (score 0):

If you can use CSS, then you can use `:empty` pseudo-class to hide the empty span.

```css
span:empty {
    display: none !important;
}
```

```html
<div style="border:1px solid #00b0ff; width:200px;">
    <span style="width:100%;display: inline-block;background: #00b0ff">1</span>
    <span style="display: inline; background: #ff3d00;"></span>
</div>
<hr />
<div style="border:1px solid #00b0ff; width:200px;">
    <span style="width:100%;display: inline-block;background: #00b0ff">1</span>
    <span style="display: inline-block; background: #ff3d00;"></span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You defined the first `<span>` to take 100% of the parent element's width (`style="width:100%"`). Remove this and your `<div>` will be one line high.

```html
<div style="border:1px solid #00b0ff; width:200px;">
        <span style="display: inline-block; background: #00b0ff">1</span>
        <span style="display: inline-block; background: #ff3d00;"></span>
    </div>
```